# wildcards & regex in gitignore

Tags: regex, gitignore, pcre

I'd like to write a pattern in my .gitignore which achieves the same as the pcre expression `resp-.*-[0-9]{3,}.*` How do I do this?

More generally, how do I mix wildcards, and specify the existence of at least a certain amount of numbers, followed by a file extension

Comment: Try `resp-*-[0-9][0-9][0-9]*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, that works well enough for my specific problem. I only expect 3 or 4 digits so I can just make 2 lines